# “To be in use” vs “to be at use” vs ”to be of use”

Tags: phrasal-verbs, at-in

What’s the difference between “to be in use” and “to be at use”?

I have impression that former states that something is being used, while the latter means something proves to be useful — the same as “to be of use”.

Comment: The phrase [to be at use](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+in+use%2Cbe+at+use%2C+be+of+use&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is not currently in use. Where did you see this phrase?

Comment: @Peter: I would have said the same thing, but Google does show some instances of "be at use".  For example: *Such technology could be at use in a secret space program, that runs parallel to NASA*

Comment: @GEdgar: it looks to me like the Google hits for "be at use" which aren't part of two different phrases are thinkos/typos for either "be in use" or "be of use" (I see both meanings among the Google hits, and I can imagine making this mistake by incompletely revising some text).

Comment: @GEdgar ... probably you forget that NASA receives messages in strange languages from  distant planets ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe these are confusing because of the involved preposition.

*To be in use* is similar to *to be busy, occupied or utilized*.

- *I need to use the restroom, but it **is in use** right now.*

*To be of use* means *to be useful, of utility, or helpful*.

- *I finally got into the restroom and it **is** really **of use** to me.*

I struggle to think of examples of *to be at use* like the one by GEdgar, but I've definitely seen and heard it used. The definition is restricted to *to be utilized or used*, and it does not mean *occupied*.  I believe *in use* can be used in place of *at use* without confusion in these settings.  The examples I can think of are rather unique:

- *The electronic record system we are considering **is at use** currently
  in several other facilities without problems.*