# Is it common to use "between" with the preposition "to"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it natural to say the following:

> There is going to be no office hours between 12:00 *to* 13:00.

I got this in an email and the use of *to* seems a bit awkward to me. I think of two better alternatives: either change *between* to *from* or *to* to *and*. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it's common or natural (and I'm not sure it's either) it doesn't make sense. An event can occur between two others, so there can be an absence of office hours **between 12:00 and 13:00**. Alternatively, an event can last for a given length of time, so the absence of office hours is **from 12:00 to 13:00**.

That apart, the information might be more effectively expressed as *The office will be closed from 12:00 to 13:00* or *The office will be closed between 12:00 and 13:00*.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be quite common, and you're entirely right.

> From X to Y
>   Between X and Y

I guess it's similar to [a previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80536/to-be-in-use-vs-to-be-at-use-vs-to-be-of-use) where Peter Shor commented that such confusion might be a thinko/typo or be caused by incompletely revising some text. But at least *between–to* is understandable in a way that *from–and* would not be.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree it is awkward, I cannot find a source that explains why. [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to) contains one definition of the word "to" as being a preposition that is "used as a function word to indicate position or relation in time." This being said, I agree that it is awkward and would suggest using the word "and" instead.

On a side note, there are a few other elements of the sentence that add to its awkwardness. The most important one would be subject/verb agreement. The subject of this sentence, "office hours," is a plural noun. ([Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/office-hours?q=office%20hours) agrees with me). Therefore, the sentence should read "There are going" rather than "There is going."

Comment: If the sentence read _There will be no office hour between 12:00 and 13:00_, the issue of singularity/plurality would not arise. Because there's only one hour in that 60-minute interval, it has to be singular to make sense. If it read _The office {is / will be} closed from 12:00 to 13:00_ or _Office hours {will be / are} suspended between 12:00 and 13:00_, there would be no issue at all. Simple, clear, brief, and literate save the day.